# Input email validation jquery IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

Im trying to check with jQuery if a input type email is filled correctly.
I used the following code but it doesn't work on IE9.

```
if($(this).attr('type') === 'email' && $(this).is(':valid'))
```

The console returns "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: valid"

Answer (score 0):

IE9 still not efficient for perfect rendering of JQuery So i recommend to use regular Javascript for email validation check.

```
function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}
```

And call it here :

```
if( !isEmail(emailaddress)) { /* do stuff here */ }
```

Comment: in this case I simply want to check if the input email is valid so I prefer not to use regex for it

Comment: have u tried using prop
if($(this).prop('type') === 'email' && $(this).is(':valid'))

Comment: the problem is in is(':valid'), not in $(this).attr('type')